# Elegant way in PowerShell to simplify a table with duplicate entries in one column, aggregating values in another column

Tags: arrays, powershell, object, duplicates

From an external source I obtain a dataset that is in essence an object array with 2 columns. In one column A, duplicate values can occur. For these duplicate values, I want to aggregate the rows so that the different values in column B are stored in an array.
For example the input table $animals looks like this:

cat | mammal

dog | mammal

shark | fish

I want an output table $animals2 that looks like this:

{cat, dog} | mammal

shark | fish

I am confused as to how to optimally define the new table (using pscustomobject, select-object, new-object/add-member) and how to efficiently add rows to this table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Group-Object` to group the objects in the array by the value of the second column, then create one new object per group:

```
$animals = ConvertFrom-Csv @'
Species|Class
cat|mammal
dog|mammal
shark|fish
'@ -Delimiter '|'

$animals2 = $animals |Group-Object -Propert Class |ForEach-Object {
  [pscustomobject]@{
    Species = $_.Group.Species |Sort-Object -Unique   # Remove `|Sort-Object -Unique` to get the full species list (including duplicates)
    Class = $_.Name
  }
}
```

Default table formatting of `$animals2` now shows you exactly what you expect:

```
PS ~> $animals2 |Format-Table

Species    Class
-------    -----
{cat, dog} mammal
shark      fish
```

Comment: If you want to remove duplicates you can add  "| Select-Object -Property Species, Class -Unique" immediately between "$animals |" and "Group-Object"

Comment: @Mike That only works if duplicates appear in sequence, I've updated the answer

Comment: I thought Select-Object -Unique didn't need to be sequential like Get-Unique. Maybe this was only in later versions of Powershell.  1,2,3,4,5,5,4,3,2,1 | Select-Object -Unique  seems to work properly.

Comment: @Mike It might work in 5.0 and up (not at a terminal right now to test unfortunately), but `Select-Object -Unique` has been very wonky in previous version

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for. Elegant and short. Thanks!

Comment: @Adriaan That's great, you're welcome! Consider marking my answer "accepted" by clicking the checkmark on the left :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your table of $anmimals looks like what I've defined, you can use the following:

```
$animals = '[{"name": "cat", "class": "mammal"}, {"name": "dog", "class": "mammal"}, {"name": "shark", "class": "fish"}]' | ConvertFrom-Json

# create an empty hashtable
$zoo = @{}

# loop through array of animals
foreach ($animal in $animals) {

    # look for existing class in $zoo hashtable
    if ($zoo.ContainsKey($animal.class)) {
        # check to make sure the animal name doesn't already exist
        if ($zoo[$animal.class] -notcontains $animal.name) {
            $zoo[$animal.class] += $animal.name
        }
    } else {
        # create a new class and add the name into the array
        $zoo[$animal.class] = [System.Collections.ArrayList] @()
        $zoo[$animal.class] += $animal.name
    }
}

$zoo
```